# Who manufactures Google's Tensor Processing Units?

Tags: tensorflow, hardware, google

Does google manufacture TPUs? I know that google engineers are the ones responsible for the design, and that google is the one using them, but which company is responsible for the actual manufacturing of the chip?

Answer (score 3):

Google has not released the manufacturing details for their TPUs. However, it's suspected that they're produced by either Taiwan Semiconductor Manufacturing or GlobalFoundries, as these are some of the largest companies in the industry.

[Source](https://www.recode.net/2016/5/20/11719392/google-ai-chip-tpu-questions-answers)